# org cycle visibility of drawers

Tags: org-mode

I use drawers extensively. As a result, They tend to get long.I would like a mechanism to fold them like headlines. I found [`outline-show-all` command](https://orgmode.org/manual/Global-and-local-cycling.html#Global-and-local-cycling) which makes drawers visible. I would like a global, headline specific and headline recursive mechanisms for toggling the visibility of drawers.

Comment: I don't use a current version of org-mode, but back in the day (a few years ago), I wrote up an answer describing how to completely hide the `:PROPERTIES:` drawer *including* the aforementioned line.  Towards the end of the answer, I wrote-up a snippet that modifies the behavior of cycling so as to *add* an additional level of toggling visibility/hiding.  To do that, I modified `org-cycle-internal-local` with a few lies of code mentioned in the answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17492723/2112489  Perhaps something of that nature will still work, but I haven't tested it recently.

Answer (score 1):

For now I figured out that running `org-mode` on file automatically folds everything including drawers. Doesn't have the granularity that I am looking for but a great counter part for `outline-show-all`.

Comment: See also `org-hide-drawer-all`.

Comment: @jagrg it doesn't seem to me that `org-hid-drawer-all` function exists.

Comment: You're right. Not in the version that ships with Emacs. Anyhow, it's in the master branch.

Comment: @jagrg I see. I will try it out.

Comment: N.B. The default has changed so initially the file is *NOT* folded any longer: everything is shown, the rationale being that that is less surprising to Org mode beginners, who might otherwise wonder where all the text went. If you want to keep the old behavior, then you can customize `org-startup-folded` to have the value `fold` instead of `showeverything`.